# How to get rest of the request in serializer in python django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm programming a survey application. I have model `AnsewerSet` that holds answers for all questions in one `Survey`. This is part of my `models.py`:

```
class AnswerSet(models.Model):
   survey = models.ForeignKey('Survey', models.CASCADE, related_name='answer_sets')

class Answer(models.Model):
   answer_set = models.ForeignKey(AnswerSet, models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, models.CASCASE, related_name='answers')

   text = models.TextField()
```

I would like to create new `AnswerSet` with the following json `POST`:

```
{
  survey_id: 1,
  answers: [
    {
      text: 'I like that.'
    },
    {
      text: 'Don't do that!'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is an answer for a `Survey` that has 2 text questions.

I would like to create a serializer that is DRY - I don't want to implement everything myself in `.validate()` and `.create()` methods. I have something like this so far:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Answer
      fields = ('id', 'text', 'answer_set', 'question')
      read_only_fields = ('id',)


class AnswerSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AnswerSet
        fields = ('id', 'survey', 'answers')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

There are multiple problems. First is that every answer requires answer_set and question (answer_set is clearly defined - I'm just creating that one, the question is defined by survey and position in the list of answers [questions are ordered]).
The second problem is I'm using ListSerializer (that many=True option) for the creation and there is no default behaviour for that. But that can be solved by creating custom ListSerializer but that is too complex for this minimal example.

So I'm asking how to Modify AnswerSetSerializer and AnswerSerializer so that I don't need to specify everything multiple times. Right now Every request needs to look like this:

```
{
  survey_id: 1,
  answers: [
    {
      text: 'I like that.'
      answer_set: ?, // not yet created
      question: 1 // first question of survey #1
    },
    {
      text: 'Don't do that!'
      answer_set: ?, // not yet created
      question: 2 // second question of survey #1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note that your "JSON" isn't JSON at all, the keys aren't quoted, you use single quotes instead of double and there is an unescaped single quote within a single quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you will have to override create (post) method in your view. Or try to use `to_representation` method of serializers.Serializer